# Root Router certificate issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

In my work we test some Chinese router and authentication server, to enterprise secure WIFI connection.This device have root certificate, that I need to install in windows mmc, before connecting, and when I start to connect by windows WiFi gui, I must choose this certificate.
But unfortunately the expire date of certificate was mistakenly marked on 2003,so it’s expired, and I even can’t see it in windows wifi GUI, for choosing. 
My question is: Can I change the date of this build in certificate in someway,  or maybe to change it to my own certificate buy the firmware upgrade or something else.
Someone met with such a problem, on the example of any other similar device?
 Thanks

Comment: If the certificate is expired you will have to deal with that fact.  There is no way to change the date of an certificate without replacing the entire certificate.

Comment: You might be able to set your clock back on your device to very temporarily bypass the issue.

Comment: I try to do so, but because a start date of certificate is 2016, it's doesn't from the other side hh, tnx

Comment: But u know some way, to replace it, in the raouter storage?  Or  I only need to contact the vendor, and ask to replace the device to new one?